# Split by space preserving string inside curly braces

Tags: python, regex

```
str = "cmd -opt1 { a b c  d e f g h } -opt2"
```

I want output like this:

```
[ 'cmd', '-opt1', '{ a b c  d e f g h }', '-opt2' ]
```

Comment: So where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it? That appears to be command line input, why are you parsing it manually rather than getting it via `sys.argv`?

Comment: This string is not from command line input.

Comment: So where *is* it from? This is likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that can be solved *before* you reach this step.

Comment: I am parsing a file that contains these command. These command are given on tcl prompt. Tcl treats everything inside {} as a string. 
I also want to parse command  with recursive curly "cmd -opt1 { a b {c d} e f} -opt2"

Comment: There are quite a few SO questions on parsing TCL format in Python already (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5558276/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26288633/3001761); have you looked at any of them? That kind of background information really helps people point you to the best information.

Comment: I have got this link - closest to my problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808913/split-string-at-commas-except-when-in-bracket-environment. But i guess there should be a easier solution also.

Comment: *"i guess there should be a easier solution also"* - why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, don't try to split, use `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'{[^}]*}|\S+', 'cmd -opt1 { a b c  d e f g h } -opt2')
['cmd', '-opt1', '{ a b c  d e f g h }', '-opt2']
```

if you have to deal with nested curly brackets, the re module doesn't suffice, you need to use the ["new" regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that has the recursion feature.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'[^{}\s]+|{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*+}', 'cmd -opt1 { a b {c d} e f} -opt2')
['cmd', '-opt1', '{ a b {c d} e f}', '-opt2']
```

Where `(?R)` refers to the whole pattern itself.

or this one (that is better):

```
regex.findall(r'[^{}\s]+|{[^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+}', 'cmd -opt1 { a b {c d} e f} -opt2')
```

Comment: I also want to parse command with curly inside curly braces e.g. "cmd -opt1 { a b {c d} e f} -opt2". So output like : ['cmd', '-opt1', '{ a b {c  d} e f}', '-opt2']. Is this also possible somehow ?

Comment: @DeepakY: Yes it is possible, but not with the re module, you need to use the "new" regex module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex that allows recursive patterns: `regex.findall(r'[^{}\s]+|{(?>[^{}]+|(?R))*}', 'cmd...`

Answer (score 3):

```
\s+(?![^{]*})
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jV9oV2/6

Answer (score 1):

Do take a look at [the `argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), since I assume you are writing code to parse the arguments of your program.  Normally these arguments are stored in `sys.argv`, so you don't even need to care about splitting the command line string.  If you insist on using the command line, you may convert your argument string to an argument list with the `str.split` method.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='whatever cmd does.')
parser.add_argument('--opt1', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='integers')

options = parser.parse_args()

for n in options.opt1:
   # do something with n
```

Comment: I believe the `parse_args` method expects a list, like it would get from `sys.argv`; will it work correctly on a string?

Comment: It uses `sys.argv` by default.  It will not work on a string (will treat it as a list of characters)

Comment: So if the OP has a *string*, how does this help them? You should at least include that caveat clearly in the answer.

Comment: *"you may convert your argument string to an argument list with the `str.split` method"* - that is **exactly what they're having trouble with**, as their string contains some spaces they want to split on and some they don't...

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe.  I have a knack for pointing towards solutions that are not directly related to the question.  

Don't you think this is a design issue: parsing a string that's going to be used by another program?  Not using standard available components, like here, leads to tons of code that aren't really needed.

That's why I posted this answer.

Comment: *"Don't you think this is a design issue"* - I think it is, potentially, and have tried to clarify with the OP why this is a requirement!

Answer (score 0):

Just split on the `{` and `}` then split the separate parts by a regular space:

```
str = "cmd -opt1 { a b c d e f g h } -opt2"
>>> a, b = str.split("{")
>>> c, d = b.split("}")
>>> a.split() + ["{{{0}}}".format(c)] + d.split()
['cmd', '-opt1', '{ a b c d e f g h }', '-opt2']
```